# unable to download deb packages from a private repo

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am trying to setup a private apt repo using [this](http://www.plankandwhittle.com/a-debianor-ubuntu-mirror-to-call-your-own/). Have followed the instructions closely. After setting up everything `sudo apt-get update` works fine (I see Packages file being fetched from apt-repo) but when I try to install a package it fails(I downloaded .deb of haproxy using `sudo apt-get -d install haproxy`.

```
Err http://ec2-54-220-154-205.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/packages/ ./ haproxy 1.4.24-1
404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ec2-54-220-154-205.eu-west1.compute.amazonaws.com/packages//home/ubuntu/packages//h/haproxy_1.4.24-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
```

As you can see the URL to the deb package is incorrect.

This path (/home/ubuntu/packages//h/haproxy_1.4.24-1_amd64.deb) is read from Packages file which is generate by dpkg-scanpackages

`dpkg-scanpackages ~/private /dev/null | gzip -9c > ~/private/Packages.gz`.

(I am not 100% sure if it is a dpkg-scanpackages issue or a nginx config issue, my experience with nginx is not a whole lot).

Any help in trying to fix this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well in case some one else get stuck on something similar:
I got it working, issue was that I was running

```
dpkg-scanpackages
```

from `/home/ubuntu` and hence the whole path  was being added to the deb package in `Packages.gz.` I executed the same command from the packages directory and I am able to successfully download the pkgs.